Conditions required for the orbit of a set of positive measure to cover state space?
Suppose $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu, T)$ is a measure-preserving dynamical system with $T$ invertible.
I am wondering what properties the dynamical system would need to have in order for the following to be true: for every positive measure subset $A \subset X$, there exists an $n$ such that
$$
A \cup T^{-1}(A) \cup \cdots \cup T^{-n}(A) \supset X,
$$
(or, since $T$ is taken to be invertible, $A \cup T^{}(A) \cup \cdots \cup T^{n}(A) \supset X$).
This property seems to hold for a variety of dynamical systems, such as irrational rigid circle rotations.  So, my question is, what are the necessary and sufficient conditions for this to hold?  If not known, are there examples of "chaotic" (i.e. strongly mixing) dynamical systems for which this property does hold?  This seems to hold for polygonal billiards, and likely "chaotic" billiards (i.e. Bunimovich Stadium) for instance, but I cannot prove it.
What conditions must a dynamical system satisfy in order for the following weaker properties to hold?

For every positive measure subset $A$ of $X$, there exists an $n$ such that
$$
\mu[A \cup T^{-1}(A) \cup \cdots \cup T^{-n}(A)] = 1.
$$
For every positive measure subset $A$ of $X$, and every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $n$ such that
$$
\mu[A \cup T^{-1}(A) \cup \cdots \cup T^{-n}(A)] \geq 1-\epsilon.
$$


Not all rigid rotations! If it is a rational rotation you can find invariant sets $A$ with $0<\mu(A)<1$, so that $A\cup T^{-1}\cup \ldots T^{-k}(A)=A\neq X$.
Ergodicity is required for condition 1, since if $A$ is invariant with $0<\mu(A)<1$ then the measure of the union will be $\mu(A)<1$. But it's not sufficient, consider a Bernoulli shift on two symbols $\{0,1\}$ and $A$ the cylinder $\{\omega | \omega_0=0\}$, for any $N>0$ you can find a set of positive measure that takes more than $N$ iterates to enter $A$, for example $\{\omega| \omega_0=\omega_2=\ldots \omega_{N+1}=1\}$.
What is estabilished is existence of a set $A$ satisfing confition 2:
Theorem (Rohklin): For an ergodic automorphism in a probability space $(X,\mu)$ with no atoms, for any $\epsilon>0$ there is a set $E$ and a number $N>0$ with $\mu(\cup_{k=0}^N T^kE)>1-\epsilon$, $E\cap T^{k}E=\emptyset$.
Now what you can get for any set $A$ of positive measure is $X=\cup_k^\infty T^{-k}A$ up to null sets, since by Birkhoff Ergodic Theorem a.e $x$ enters $A$.

Unless I'm really missing something...
Your property (2) is equivalent to ergodicity, and (1) is equivalent to ergodicity and your measure being atomic. (In particular, it does not hold for irrational rotations, as seems to have been claimed.)
To see that (2) holds for ergodic systems, just note that for any $A$ of positive measure, the set $U = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} T^{-n} A$ is $T$-invariant of positive measure (the preimage of $U$ is contained in $U$, and has the same measure by invariance, so is equal to $U$ up to set of measure $0$). So by ergodicity, $\mu(U) = 1$, and by continuity from below, your (2) holds.
(2) fails for non-ergodic systems as already explained.
To see that (1) fails for non-atomic measures, take arbitrary sets $B_n$ ($n > 0$) with $0 < \mu(B_n) < 9^{-n}$, and define $A = \bigcup_n \bigcup_{i = 0}^{3^n - 1} T^i B_n$. Then $\mu(A) \leq \sum_n \sum_{i = 0}^{3^n - 1} 9^{-n} = 1/2$, so $\mu(A^c) > 0$. But, for any $n$, $\bigcup_{j = 0}^{3^n - 1} T^{-j} A^c$ is disjoint from $B_n$, and so not of full measure. Since $n$ was arbitrary, your (1) fails.
That (1) holds for an ergodic atomic measure (which is just a periodic orbit) is trivial.
